# Table has some tr with bigger height

Tags: html, html-table

As you can see in this fiddle 
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vaL9Lpqm/)

The table starts with all the rows having the same height but later they have bigger heights, why is that?

This is just some portion of the table, please check the fiddle

```
    <table border="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
 height="190">
    <tbody>
      <tr bgcolor="#ffffcc">
        <td class="Normal" style="width: 116px;"
 height="16" valign="top">
        <p style="" align="center"><strong><font
 face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">
        <span
 style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial; color: blue"> <font
 color="#000066"> FECHA</font></span></font></strong></p>
        </td>
        <td class="Normal" height="16" valign="top"
 width="90">
        <p style="" align="center"><strong><font
 face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">
        <span
 style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial;"> <font
 color="#000066">Número</font></span></font></strong></p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3" class="Normal" height="16"
 valign="top" width="357">
        <p style="" align="center"><strong><font
 color="#990000" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"
 size="2"><span
 style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial; color: blue"> <font
 color="#000066">Variaciones</font></span></font></strong></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="Normal" style="width: 116px;"
 height="22" valign="top">
        <div align="center"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="Normal" bgcolor="#ffffcc"
 height="22" valign="top" width="90">
        <p style="" align="center"><strong><font
 color="#000066" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"
 size="2"><span
 style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial; color: blue">Indice</span></font></strong></p>
        </td>
        <td class="Normal" bgcolor="#ffffcc"
 height="22" valign="top" width="357">
        <p style="" align="center"><strong><font
 color="#000066" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"
 size="2"><span
 style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial; color: blue">Mensual</span></font></strong></p>
        </td>
        <td class="Normal" bgcolor="#ffffcc"
 height="22" valign="top" width="357">
        <p style="" align="center"><strong><font
 face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">
        <span
 style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial; color: blue">Acum.
del Año</span></font></strong></p>
        </td>
```

Comment: That HTML looks like its from 1995

Comment: yeah, it is very old, i am using javascript to correct it because there a a lot of documents of this type,

Answer (score 1):

This happens because some TD tags have P tags inside them. Use span instead.

Do this:

```
 <tr>
        <td class="Normal" style="width: 116px;" height="13" valign="top">
          <span style="" align="center"><strong style="font-weight: 400;"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">
    <span style="font-family: Arial;">31/01/<a name="2009">2009</a></span></font></strong></span>

</tr>
```

Instead of:

```
<tr>
        <td class="Normal" style="width: 116px;" height="13" valign="top">
          <p style="" align="center"><strong style="font-weight: 400;"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">
    <span style="font-family: Arial;">31/01/<a name="2009">2009</a></span></font></strong></p>
        </td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the row with 28/02/2009 and the rows below that are higher is very simple:

- in the rows above 28/02/2009, the first table cell has no `<p>` element;
- in the row with 28/02/2009 and those below it, the first table cell has a `<p>` element.

I assume that the HTML code was created in a WYSIWYG editor; that would explain why it is so bloated. The code can be made much smaller by removing all direct formatting from the HTML code and replacing it with CSS style rules. By direct formatting, I mean things like

- `align="center" height="1" valign="top" width="90"` on the `<td>` elements,
- `style="font-weight: 400;"` on the `<strong>` elements inside the `<td>` elements,
- the entire `<span style="font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Tahoma;">...</span>` elements,
- the entire `<font face="Arial" size="2">...</font>` elements (except for their content, obviously).

You would then end up with something like the following:

```
<tr>
  <th>28/02/2009</th>
  <td>113,59</td>
  <td>0,57</td>
  <td>6,81</td>
  <td>14,56</td>
</tr>
```

Then, you need to make up your mind about the font face, the font size, etc., because some of the direct formatting was contradictory (Tahoma on the `span` elements, Arial on `font` elements, ...) and create CSS rules for the table.

Comment: "... and .."? To be continued?

Answer (score 0):

I would just use css to set the height of the `tr` elements:

```
tr {
    height: 40px; /* or whatever else */
}
```

**EDIT**: you can also try setting the height of `td`:

```
td {
    height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: it doesnt work setting the td or tr height in the css, but if i set it in the element style when i debug the css (F12) it works.. for individual tr